# OpenGL matrix multiplication results in odd floating point behavior

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, rotational-matrices

I have a basic OpenGL program written in LWJGL for java. I'm just starting to look into rotation matrices after reading up on why it's a bad idea to use pitch, yaw and roll variables. However, as matrices are more difficult to work with, I am writing a function that takes yaw, pitch and roll and converts them into a rotation matrix, which is then multiplied with the Modelview matrix. My code is as follows:

```
public static void loadRotationalMatrix(double pitch, double yaw, double roll)
{
    FloatBuffer Ry = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(16 * Double.SIZE).asFloatBuffer();
    FloatBuffer Rx = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(16 * Double.SIZE).asFloatBuffer();
    FloatBuffer Rz = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(16 * Double.SIZE).asFloatBuffer();

    Rx.put(new float[]
        {
            1, 0, 0, 0,
            0, (float) cos(pitch), (float) sin(pitch), 0,
            0, (float) -sin(pitch), (float) cos(pitch), 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1
        });
    Ry.put(new float[]
        {
            (float) cos(yaw), 0, (float) -sin(yaw),  0,
            0, 1, 0, 0,
            (float) sin(yaw), 0, (float) cos(yaw), 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1
        });
    Rz.put(new float[]
        {
            (float) cos(roll), (float) sin(roll), 0, 0,
            (float) -sin(roll), (float) cos(roll), 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 1, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1
        });

    GL11.glMultMatrix(Rx);
    GL11.glMultMatrix(Ry);
    GL11.glMultMatrix(Rz);
}
```

To begin, I passed `0, 0, 0` to this function, which I expected to have no effect on the rendered scene. However, the simple square I was drawing disappeared after the function call. To debug, I used `glGetFloat` to access the modelview matrix and see what happened.

This is where things get strange (for me at least): before I call my function, the retrieved `FloatBuffer` storing the modelview matrix is

```
4.6006E-41, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.6006E-41, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.6006E-41, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.6006E-41,
```

or, more readable,

```
4.6006E-41, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 4.6006E-41, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 4.6006E-41, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.6006E-41,
```

and everything renders normally.

After my call, the matrix becomes

```
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
```

and my test square disappears.

What is happening? Are my matrices created incorrectly? Is there something I do not understand about `glMultMatrix`? Is there something I need to enable or disable? Why does the normal matrix have those weird floats in it? Isn't it supposed to be the identity matrix (with 1's)?

EDIT:

If `BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16 * Float.SIZE);` is used instead of `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(16 * Float.SIZE).asFloatBuffer();`, the the byte-ordering problems mentioned go away and the `4.6006E-41`'s becomes `1.0` as expected. However, the matrix still transforms from the identity to pure zeroes.

Comment: You probably need to flip your buffers before you call GL11.glMultMatrix(...).

Comment: Maybe I meant that you should rewind the buffer.  Try that.  It looks like your matrices and buffer allocations are solid to me.  I haven't used LWJGL very much, but I imagine that GL11.glMultMatrix() is multiplying the modelview matrix by the passed in matrix. If there's no change with rewinding the buffer, post some code so I can see where you call this loadRotationMatrix(...) function.

Comment: It won't matter if all your angles are zero, but FYI there's a sign error in your yaw matrix (one of the `sin`s should have a plus sign and one a minus sign, so that taking the transpose of the matrix is equivalent to flipping the sign of the angle).

Comment: @MikeDinsdale Thanks. Fixed that, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Nathan After applying the fixes mentioned in my edits, this worked. Thank you; the problem is solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This is really an extended comment, with code)

There is definitely a byte order problem here. I ran the following:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    float f = (float)4.6006E-41;
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(Float.floatToIntBits(f)));
  }
}
```

and got output 803f

Float 1.0 is big-endian 0x3f800000.

Comment: The byte ordering is fixed, but my main problem remains. See my edits.

Comment: Accepted as this was fundamental in solving the problem.